# Incompatibility of two C++ libraries

Tags: c++, libraries, incompatibility

I need *OpenXLSX* (from troldal) and *DuckX* (the only .docx library). But they use two different libraries that declare the same functions (zippy and miniz. zippy being based on miniz).

I tried to install Duckx, OpenXLSX too, but i'm nake and I didn't succeed.

I want to use both in project. But zippy is based on miniz and DuckX use miniz, so, they declared the same functions

Comment: If they are open source, you could modify one to remove the collisions.  You could also contact the developers and ask them to do so.  It does seem odd that they would be using the same namespaces and/or global functions though, zippy should have changed those.

Comment: Yes, they're OpenSource, I'll try to modify them. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If this Zippy library is based on Miniz, and provide a compatible interface, it shouldn't be very hard to replace one with the other in either the DuckX or the OpenXSLX libraries. Depending on how the projects are configured, you can make them look first for one of the libraries, and if not found then look for the other. Make it clean and nice and you could create a pull request for the maintainers of the original packages, so your "fix" can help others in the future.

Comment: But Zippy have is own prefix, it don't use the Miniz prefix. If I make look of one first, (Zippy for example) I don't think DuckX work beacause he use the miniz prefix.

Comment: If Zippy has its own prefix, how come it conflicts with Miniz?

Comment: Is the error at compile time or at the link? Could you provide the error message?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I think because they have the same function names (maybe it doesn't matter, since they have a different prefix, and then I'll learn something else about C++).

Comment: @Sandburg It occurs at compile time. Here is the [error](https://pastebin.com/PwVMUC6J) (pastebin link)